# Error creating aws_s3_notification with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm currently having an issue with my aws_s3_notification resource creation. Whenever I attempt to deploy this resource, I receive this error 
`Error putting S3 notification configuration: InvalidArgument: Unable to validate the following destination configurations`

I've tried setting depends_on parameters and adjusting permissions. One interesting thing is in my main.tf file, I'm creating two lambda functions. Both are extremely similar (just vary by code). My "controller" configuration deploys with no issue but my "chunker" function seems to have an issue creating the s3_notification.. I have included both configs for comparison.

```
#S3
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "ancb" {
  for_each = toset(var.ancb_bucket)

  bucket = format("ancb-%s-%s-%s",var.env,var.product_name,each.value)
  acl = "private"

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  tags = {
      Environment = var.env
      Terraform = true
  }
}
#Chunker
resource "aws_lambda_function" "ancb_chunker" {

  function_name = format("ancb-chunker-%s-%s",var.env,var.product_name)

  s3_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["config"].id
  s3_key = var.lambda_zip_chunker

  handler = "handler.chunk"
  runtime = "nodejs8.10"

  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn

  environment {
      variables = {
          ORIGINAL_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["original"].id
          TO_PROCESS_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["to-process"].id
          ENVIRONMENT = var.env
          CHUNK_SIZE = 5000
      }
  }
  tags = {
      Environment = var.env
      Terraform = true
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket_object.ancb["chunker.zip"],
    aws_s3_bucket.ancb["chunker"]
  ]
}
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "ancb_chunker_s3" {

  statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket-Chunker"
  action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.ancb_controller.arn
  principal = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["original"].arn
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "chunker" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["original"].id

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.ancb_chunker.arn
    events = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_lambda_permission.ancb_chunker_s3,
    aws_lambda_function.ancb_chunker,
    aws_s3_bucket.ancb["original"]
  ]
}
#Controller
resource "aws_lambda_function" "ancb_controller" {

  function_name = format("ancb-controller-%s-%s",var.env,var.product_name)

  s3_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["config"].id
  s3_key = var.lambda_zip_controller

  handler = "handler.controller"
  runtime = "nodejs8.10"

  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn

  environment {
      variables = {
          DESTINATION_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["destination"].id
          ENVIRONMENT = var.env
          ERROR_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["error"].id
          GEOCODIO_APIKEY = <insert>
          GEOCODIO_ENDPOINT = <insert>
          GEOCODIO_VERSION = <insert>
          ORIGINAL_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["original"].id
          SOURCE_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["source"].id
          TO_PROCESS_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["to-process"].id
          WORKING_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["working"].id
      }
  }
  tags = {
      Environment = var.env
      Terraform = true
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket_object.ancb["controller.zip"]
  ]
}
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "ancb_controller_s3" {

  statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket-Controller"
  action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.ancb_controller.arn
  principal = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["source"].arn
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "controller" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["source"].id

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.ancb_controller.arn
    events = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_lambda_permission.ancb_controller_s3,
    aws_s3_bucket.ancb["source"]
  ]
}
```

UPDATE: If I manually create the trigger and run terraform apply again, terraform is able to move forward with no problem....

Comment: Why have you removed the bucket resources from your code? This seems like an important part to me. Your question should include a [mcve] so that people can directly run your code and see the same error you do.

Comment: I apologize. I'll add the bucket resources to my code as well.

Comment: I ended up with the same solution -- manually adding the Event notification to the bucket and then terraform will apply with no problem.